# Application of the Green-Tao theorem

Tags: problem-solving, analytic-number-theory

I am currently trying to find some good exercises in analytic number theory, suitable for undergraduates.

I have mentioned the Green-Tao theorem for arithmetic progressions of primes but I am struggling to find any interesting applications/problems.

Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 4):

**Exercise/Question:** Is the Green-Tao theorem also true for *composite* numbers, i.e., 
are there arithmetic progressions $an+b$ with $gcd(a,b)=1$ of arbitrarily large length consisting only of *composite* numbers ? For example, the progression $7n+1$ gives three composite numbers $8,15,22$ for $n=1,2,3$.

Hint: A solution can be found at MSE, question $p=164513$ prime.

Edit: A problem which uses the Green-Tao theorem could be: Show that there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions consisting of numbers which are the sum of two squares.

Comment: That is a good question and is aimed at the kind of level I am looking for, but I would like a problem that somehow uses the theorem.

Comment: @fretty OK, I have edited the answer.